# Shared element transition not applying to button text

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm having a problem with shared element transition of a button between two fragments.
I'm using the navigation component to move between fragments.

Here is the code of the button in the first fragment:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/introduction_next_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/introduction_button"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/introduction_next_button_text"
            android:textColor="@color/introduction_next_button_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/introduction_button_text_size"
            android:transitionName="introduction_next_button" />
```

And this is the code of the button in the second fragment.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/introduction_next_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/introduction_button"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:transitionName="introduction_next_button"
            android:text="@string/introduction_next_button_text"
            android:textColor="@color/introduction_next_button_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/introduction_button_text_size" />
```

As you can see I changed the dimension, the margin and the padding.

This is the code of the first fragment:

```
introduction_next_button.setOnClickListener {
        val extras = FragmentNavigator.Extras
            .Builder()
            .addSharedElement(introduction_next_button, "introduction_next_button")
            .build()

        findNavController(this)
            .navigate(
                R.id.action_introductionFragment1_to_introductionFragment2,
                null,
                null,
                extras
            )
    }
```

While this is the code of the second fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
}
```

The transition works good but there is an issue with the text of the button which jump to 0,0 (relative to the button) as soon as the animation is started and doesn't follow the animation. 
You can see it in the image attached.
[image]

Any suggestion?

Maybe the `android.R.transition.move` I used requires some adjustments?

Regards